# Android Studio code seem to be working alright but I get this run time error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The code doesn't have any errors but it shows this during runtime:

*"Error running activity the activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter"*

Comment: You have a malformed Manifest.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the activity you want to start inside manifest

```
 <activity android:name=".put your started activity name here"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```